# Figuring out the output of the code

Tags: java

I am given a code below and I need to find the output. Obviously, I compiled the code and found the output to be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
but I don't understand why.

```
public class ArrayTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int k=0;k<numbers.length;k++)
        System.out.print(numbers[k]+" ");
    doSomething(numbers,2);
    for (int k=0;k<numbers.length;k++)
        System.out.print(numbers[k]+" ");
  }
  public static void doSomething(int[] n, int i){
    for (int j=0; j<n.length;j++)
      n[j] += i;
  }
}
```

Would anyone like to break down the code for me?

Comment: When i ran your code i got `1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7 `

Comment: I don't get the output you state.

Comment: that's not the output.

Comment: Try debugging or tracing by hand.

Answer (score 5):

The output is actually `1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7`.

`doSomething(int[], int)` simply adds `i` to each element in the array `n`.

The first for loop will print all of the numbers in the array ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5 "), and then the call to `doSomething` will add 2 to each number in the array. Thus your new array when printed in the following for loop is `3, 4, 5, 6, 7`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add new line  `System.out.print("\n");` like this:

```
     for (int k=0;k<numbers.length;k++)
        System.out.print(numbers[k]+" ");
        System.out.print("\n");
        doSomething(numbers,2);
```

And you'll have output:

```
 first  for loop gives: 1 2 3 4 5 
 second for loop gives: 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is wrong i think.

The first `for` loop prints out `1 2 3 4 5`

The second`for` loop prints out `3 4 5 6 7`

It just adds 2 to each number in the array :)